# Loop through an HTML table using Razor/C# to get the data in each <tr>

Tags: javascript, c#, razor, html-table, webmatrix

I have an HTML table that can dynamically have rows added or removed via Javascript. Each row has some inputs that need to be sent to my SQLCompact database via Razor/C# in WebMatrix. For example:

```html
<table id="dataTable">
  <tr id="line1">
    <td><input type="text" name="input1line1"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="input2line1"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="input3line1"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="line2">
    <td><input type="text" name="input1line2"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="input2line2"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="input3line2"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Line1 is in every table, but each table row after that is dynamically generated client-side via Javascript. How do I loop through the table using my server-side code to get the ids from the table rows and thus access the input values for entry into my database?

Comment: The server generally doesn't see the client in this way. Instead, you loop through the added rows on the **client** side, and send them to the server, usually via an ajax call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Request.Form.AllKeys` at your server side code to read all textbox data that are generated dynamically with javascript

```
foreach (string name in Request.Form.AllKeys) {
    string value = Request.Form[name];
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked great.